# C++ Dynamic Array 1 dimension non dynamic

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

Been awhile since I've programmed in C++ however I have a slight problem that I'm trying to figure out.

Is it possible to make a 2 by 2 dynamic array where 1 dimension is not dynamic?

For example

array[2][Dynamic]?

It seems like a waste to make array[dynamic][dynamic] and when I only need to use the first [0][dynamic] and second [1][dynamic] values.

Should I use another data structure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays and pointers are basically equivalent, so you can achieve this with an array of pointers:

```
int* array[2];
array[0] = new int[x];
array[1] = new int[y];
```

You can still access it as you would multidimensional array:

```
array[0][x-1] = z;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in C++11:

```
std::array<std::vector<MyClass>,2> arr;
```

Or you could use a c-style array of vectors

```
std::vector<MyClass> arr[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure but it has to be dynamic in the first dimension.

Like this for instance

```
typedef int two_int_array[2];

two_int_array* a = new two_int_array[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    a[i][0] = 1;
    a[i][1] = 2;
}
```

Of course the better way in general is to use vectors. Since you can't have a vector of arrays, a vector of structs might be better for your case.

```
struct two_int_struct
{
    int value[2];
};

std::vector<two_int_struct> a(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    a[i].value[0] = 1;
    a[i].value[1] = 2;
}
```